# Is there such a thing as non-utf8 character

Tags: c++, utf-8, stdstring

Trying to implement c++ code where we could use a non-utf8 char to be as delimiter inside a std::string.

Is there such a thing as a non-UTF-8 char ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. 0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFF are [invalid UTF-8 code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout). A UTF-8 code unit is 8 bits. If by `char` you mean an 8-bit byte, then the invalid UTF-8 code units would be `char` values that do not appear in UTF-8 encoded text.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` only knows about raw `char` values, it knows nothing about particular character encodings that use `char` to hold encoded values.

Many common UTF-8 implementations use `char` to hold encoded codeunits (though C++20 will introduce `char8_t` and `std::u8string` for this purpose instead). But other character encodings (Windows-12##, ISO-8859-#, etc) can also fit their encoded values in `char` elements, too.

Any `char` value that falls within the ASCII range (0x00 .. 0x7F) will fit in 1 `char` and map to the same codepoint value in Unicode (U+0000 .. U+007F), but any `char` value in the ANSI range but not in the ASCII range (0x80 .. 0xFF) is subject to interpretation by whatever character encoding created the `char` values.  Some encodings use 1 `char` per character, some use multiple `char`s.

So yes, there is such a thing as a "non-UTF-8 char".

Comment: But the C++-Standard still requires char to have an size of exactely 1 byte. Assuming the standard 8 bit = 1 byte, any utf8-char will allways fit into `char`

Comment: A UTF-8 *encoded codeunit* can be made to fit in a `char`, yes. But UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding, but `char` may be either *signed* or *unsigned* depending on compiler implementation. In case of *signed*, all codeunits of any Unicode codepoint above U+007F will occupy the sign bit of each `char`. Also note that although `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte in size, a byte is not guaranteed to be 8 bits on all platforms (though on most, it is) - see `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h`. UTF-7, on the other hand, would fit nicely in a `char` string without using the sign bit at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [UTF-8 standard on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Not every sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 character. Even if it's a single byte: 0x11111000, 0x11111111 are not valid first bytes in UTF-8.

Though, I doubt that it is a good idea to use a non-UTF-8 character as a delimiter. You might find certain program (like Notepad++) having issues with reading output of your strings.